# latex plot is not showing in pdf

Tags: r, pdf, plot, ggplot2, latex

I have been creating the same pdf's (with small modifications) for several years  but after I recently received a new pc (Windows 10, 64-bit), I simply can't make them anymore. I have re-installed all necessary packages but also java 32-bit in addition to 64 (as one of the many suggestions). After some modifications I can make them again, but the plots I made with ggplot2 or just plot do not appear. No room is reserved for them in the pdf, nothing. Below the code, however, with a lot of packages that might not be relevant for this example, but they are for my larger version of the pdf. My R version R-3.3.2. My R studio Version 1.0.136

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[pdftex]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{eurosym}     
\usepackage[ddmmyyyy]{datetime}
\renewcommand{\dateseparator}{.}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc} % Æ,Ø,å, æ ø,å på pc
\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}
\usepackage{spverbatim}
\definecolor{SHBLUE}{RGB}{39,170,225}
\definecolor{SHLGRAY}{RGB}{156,158,159}
\definecolor{SHDGRAY}{RGB}{88,88,90}
\definecolor{SHRED}{RGB}{192,0,0}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=0.4\textwidth}    
\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}    
\textbf{\color{SHBLUE}\Large Analysis of Animal Health Economics\color{black}} Herd ID: 
{\footnotesize\today}
The bar plot shows ...
<<bar1, echo=FALSE,warning=TRUE, message=TRUE, out.width="0.25\\linewidth",fig.width = 5,fig.height=2.9>>=
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
library(reshape)
x<-c(2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16)
y<-c(100,200,400,800,1200,1600,1800,1200)/1000
plot(x,y)
@
The results mean...
\end{document}
```

Very frustrating. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Although you are loading `ggplot2` your code uses only base graphics `plot(x,y)`?

Comment: Try commenting out `%\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE} ` (ie perhaps you are building with knitr rather than sweave)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I am using Sweave and when commenting out %\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}, it automatically comes back, as soon as I give the command to "Compile pdf".

Comment: Make sure that you are using sweave. In Rstudio set Tools > Global Opions > Sweave > Weave Rnw files using > to sweave.

Comment: yes, it is correctly set at sweave. And "Typeset LaTeX into PDF using" is set at pdfLaTeX

Comment: answer to Uwe Block: yes, loading ggplot2 was confusing, my more complex code contains a ggplot2, just to illustrate the problem I just used plot. But by not loading ggplot2 the problem does not disappear.

Comment: i figured it out. I should add "fig=TRUE". It's odd to me that this should be added, since it worked without this statement in my old computer. Might have been something with versions of packages and/or R. thanks for your help!